# Save DataFrame as Json with non unique index

Tags: python, pandas

my DF is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['POA', 'POA', 'SAN'], 'info' : [10,12,5]}, index = [4314902, 4314902, 4300803])
df.index.rename('ID_city', inplace=True)

output:

    city    info
ID_city     
4314902 POA 10
4314902 POA 12
4300803 SAN 5
```

I need to save as json oriented by index. The following command works only when each index is unique.

```
df.to_json('df.json', orient='index')
```

Is possible to save this DataFrame and when he find a duplicate index, create a array? 
My desire output:

```
{ 4314902 : [ {'city': 'POA', 'info': 10} , {'city': 'POA', 'info': 11} ]
 ,4300803 : {'city': 'SAN', 'info': 5} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of built-in Pandas functionality, that handles duplicate indexes in json orient='index' exporting.

You could of course build this manually. Merge the columns into one that contains a dict:

```
cols_as_dict = df.apply(dict, axis=1)
```

```
ID_city
4314902    {'city': 'POA', 'info': 10}
4314902    {'city': 'POA', 'info': 12}
4300803     {'city': 'SAN', 'info': 5}
```

Put rows into lists, grouped by the index:

```
combined = cols_as_dict.groupby(cols_as_dict.index).apply(list)
```

```
ID_city
4300803                         [{'city': 'SAN', 'info': 5}]
4314902    [{'city': 'POA', 'info': 10}, {'city': 'POA', ...
```

Then write the json:

```
combined.to_json() 
 '{"4300803":[{"city":"SAN","info":5}],"4314902":[{"city":"POA","info":10},{"city":"POA","info":12}]}'
```

It creates a list even if there's just a single entry per index. That should make processing actually easier than if you mix the data types (either list of elements or single element).

If you are set on the mixed type (either dict or list of several dicts), then do `combined.to_dict()`, change the lists with single elements back into their first element, and then dump the json.

Comment: Exactly what I need, Thx! I just changed `combined.to_json()` to `combined.to_dict()`.

Comment: Just a observation, for me `combined.to_dict()` preserve the one position arrays. Maybe you can edit or remove the last paragraph of your answer. `to_dict()` was useful to me because `to_json()` after the `dump` was including many '\' everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If I run the code above, `combine.to_json()` does not produce any escaped quotes. For me it puts out the string seen above, with no escapes at all. I've added the last paragraph because the example output in your question has the single object not in a list, so I wanted to show a way to provide exactly this output.

Comment: the back slash appear after the dump when I open a file and do `json.dump(combined.to_json(), outfile)`. If I do `json.dump(combined.to_dict(), outfile)` the file is perfect.

Comment: The output of `combined.to_json()` is already a JSON string. `json.dump` will dump this string as a JSON structure, ignoring that it is already JSON, and thus escaping all the characters. Just do a `combined.to_json(outfile)`, no need to invoke `json.dump`.